# Where's the download link of SSMS - ISO image?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I'm looking for the ISO image of SQL Server Management Studio, I got many results related to SQL Server, but I'm confused which one of them to download.

Comment: You are not alone in your confusion. Finding the right download of SQL Server Express or Management Studio _is_ incredibly confusing. Thankfully, Scott Hanselman's made a [blog post](http://downloadsqlserverexpress.com) to make it a lot easier to find your way.

Answer (score 2):

Download SQL Server Management Studio Express version for free.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062

Comment: Thank you, which one of this links to choose:
ENU\x64\SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe
132.3 MB
 
ENU\x64\SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU.exe
1.3 GB
 
ENU\x64\SQLEXPRWT_x64_ENU.exe
669.9 MB
 
ENU\x64\SqlLocalDB.MSI
33.0 MB
 
ENU\x64\SQLManagementStudio_x64_ENU.exe

Comment: I used ENU\x64\SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe 132.3 MB

Comment: That looks like it's SQL Server Express and may also include SSMS. But he's looking for just SSMS.

Comment: the file size is just 132.3 MB, what about this file:  SQLManagementStudio_x64_ENU.exe 950.2 MB.
there is also two versions:Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012 Service Pack 2 (SP2) Express
and: Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012 Express
??

Answer (score 1):

You can find the SQL Server Management Studio preview releases as well as previous  standalone releases here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can visit [Turbo.net and stream SSMS](https://www.turbo.net/hub/sqlserver/ssms2014) in a container, which means you don't even need to "install" it. Clever stuff. And at no cost.

It's highly likely that launching apps via containers will be the norm in a few years' time. It's great that Turbo already provides this service.